# C# SQL Server Class Connection String from a text file [error Instance failure]

Tags: c#, sql-server

I save connection string in a text file, like this :

koneksi.txt

```
Data Source=GGL-TBGIT-PC02\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=db_timbangan;user=sa;password=GGL654321
```

and this  my class connection

```
class Koneksi
{
    public System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection GetConn()
    {
        string path;
        TextReader tr = new StreamReader(@"D:\PROJECT\2.0 TIMBANGAN\TIMBANGAN\koneksi.txt");
        path = tr.ReadLine();
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();            
        conn.ConnectionString = path;
        return conn;
    }
}
```

this my login

```
Koneksi konn = new Koneksi();
    public Login()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.AcceptButton = button1;
    }

    private Boolean statusLogin(string username, string password)
    {
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn = konn.GetConn();
        conn.Open();
        string sql = "select * from tbl_login where username='" + username + "' AND password='" + password + "'";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader["username"].ToString() == username && reader["password"].ToString() == password)
            {

                return true;
            }
        }
        conn.Close();
        return false;
    }
```

when I tried to log in, the error Instance failure at **conn.Open()**

how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the connection string with only one `\`

`Data Source=GGL-TBGIT-PC02\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=db_timbangan;user=sa;password=GGL654321`

Additionally, you should be using a `using` for your SQL connection.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    //read here
    connection.Close();
}
```